# SELECT while showing difference between records

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I'm running `PostgreSQL 9.6`.

I have a table of calling records which shows how much people have talked over a `VOIP` line.

It has the structure:

```
table: voice_records

session_id | user_id | total_seconds_talked
```

I get the records between every 1-30 minutes or so, so if a user is talking for an hour I will receive multiple records for that single call.
All records for a single session will contain the same `session_id`, `user_id` but incrementing `total_seconds_talked`.

Ex.

```
234gdd-542-vffd, 1001, 5
234gdd-542-vffd, 1001, 11
234gdd-542-vffd, 1001, 532
234gdd-542-vffd, 1001, 234
234gdd-542-vffd, 1001, 1159
```

It's important to know, that I might receive the records in wrong order.

I would like to create a `VIEW` where I see the records as indivial records,
so for the example above I would get the difference between the records - and because it's a `VIEW` it should be calculated on the go, so receiving wrong order becomes corrected when `SELECT`ing the `VIEW`.

Ex.

```
SELECT * FROM voice_records WHERE session_id = '234gdd-542-vffd'

OUTPUT:

234gdd-542-vffd, 1001, 5
234gdd-542-vffd, 1001, 6
234gdd-542-vffd, 1001, 223
234gdd-542-vffd, 1001, 298
234gdd-542-vffd, 1001, 627
```

I guess it involves some sort of `SELECT` with an `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT 1`, but I'm really kind of stuck on how to do this correctly, and most effeciently.
And also which `INDEX`es should be in place.

**UPDATE**

Example simply `SELECT`:

```
 user_id |   session_id    | seconds_this_time
---------+-----------------+--------
 1001    | 234gdd-542-vffd | 313557
 1001    | 234gdd-542-vffd | 314844
 1001    | 234gdd-542-vffd | 338980
 1001    | 234gdd-542-vffd | 507246
 1001    | 234gdd-542-vffd | 509233
 1001    | 234gdd-542-vffd | 509441
 1001    | 234gdd-542-vffd | 553260
 1001    | 234gdd-542-vffd | 556985
 1001    | 234gdd-542-vffd | 581958
 1001    | 234gdd-542-vffd | 586079
 1001    | 234gdd-542-vffd | 597381
 1001    | 234gdd-542-vffd | 597745
 1001    | 234gdd-542-vffd | 611672
 1001    | 234gdd-542-vffd | 709918
 1001    | 234gdd-542-vffd | 725510
 1001    | 234gdd-542-vffd | 743432
 1001    | 234gdd-542-vffd | 743835
 1001    | 234gdd-542-vffd | 743835
 1001    | 234gdd-542-vffd |
```

With `lag` function:

```
 user_id |   session_id    | seconds_this_time
---------+-----------------+--------
 1001    | 234gdd-542-vffd |
 1001    | 234gdd-542-vffd |   1287
 1001    | 234gdd-542-vffd |  24136
 1001    | 234gdd-542-vffd | 168266
 1001    | 234gdd-542-vffd |   1987
 1001    | 234gdd-542-vffd |    208
 1001    | 234gdd-542-vffd |  43819
 1001    | 234gdd-542-vffd |   3725
 1001    | 234gdd-542-vffd |  24973
 1001    | 234gdd-542-vffd |   4121
 1001    | 234gdd-542-vffd |  11302
 1001    | 234gdd-542-vffd |    364
 1001    | 234gdd-542-vffd |  13927
 1001    | 234gdd-542-vffd |  98246
 1001    | 234gdd-542-vffd |  15592
 1001    | 234gdd-542-vffd |  17922
 1001    | 234gdd-542-vffd |    403
 1001    | 234gdd-542-vffd |      0
 1001    | 234gdd-542-vffd |
```

Comment: Here you can create a b-tree index which is the default, for "session_id" and "user_id" and use the "talked_time" in order as desc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You apparently want `lag()`:

```
select user_id, session_id,
       (total_seconds_talked -
        lag(total_seconds_talked, 1, 0::bigint) over (partition by user_id, session_id order by total_seconds_talked)
       ) as seconds_this_time
from voice_records;
```

Based on your description, the values might change for calls in progress, because the records are not received in order.

EDIT:

If for some reason you cannot use the three argument form of `lag()`, just use `coalesce()`:

```
select user_id, session_id,
       (total_seconds_talked -
        coalesce(lag(total_seconds_talked) over (partition by user_id, session_id order by total_seconds_talked), 0)
       ) as seconds_this_time
from voice_records;
```

Comment: I'm getting the error `function lag(bigint, integer, integer) does not exist`

Comment: @AlfredBalle . . . the function most certainly does exist:  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-window.html.

Comment: I agree, it works without the `, 1, 0)` but with the parameters it complains. Without the two last parameters it does calculate, but are missing the very first entry (in my case the 5 minutes records).

Comment: @AlfredBalle: try `lag(total_seconds_talked, 1::bigint, 0::bigint) ...`

Comment: Gives me `function lag(bigint, bigint, bigint) does not exist`.

Comment: I've just updated my initial post with output from regular `SELECT` and your example without `, 1, 0)` in the `lag` function. Shows the first entry missing.

Comment: @AlfredBalle: `lag(total_seconds_talked, 1, 0::bigint)` works. The default value must be the same type as the first parameter, but the "offset" can only be an integer

Comment: Ah, solved it `lag(total_seconds_talked, 1, 0::bigint)` of course. Seems to work. THANK you.

Comment: You were quicker :) What would be most effecient, to put a `INDEX` on `(user_id, session_id, total_seconds_talked)` or individual `INDEX` on each column?

Comment: @AlfredBalle . . . Wow.  I'm surprised the cast is needed.  It makes sense, but I don't use big ints very often.